# Equivalence relations on a set

Tags: equivalence-relations

I am to find how many equivalence relations are there on a set $\left\{1, 2, 3\right\}$. How it can be counted? I will appreciate a step by step solution because I'm new to set theory. Thanks!

Comment: It's easy. Do you know the proposition that every partition of a set $X$ defines one equivalence relation on $X$ and, conversly, every equivalence relation on $X$ defines a partition on $X$?

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. And it really makes things easier. So there will be 5 equivalence relations?

Comment: Yup, you got it!

Comment: That's great! Thanks! :)

Comment: Have a look at these links; studing the proof of that theorem is central to understanding equivalence relations. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333375/proof-of-theorem-about-equivalence-classes and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31656/every-equivalence-relation-on-a-set-s-defines-a-corresponding-partition-and-v

Comment: Nice links, @Pythagoricus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented befotre, every partition of a set $X$ defines one equivalence relation on $X$ and, conversly. The different partitions of $X=\{1,2,3\}$ are:
$$\begin{aligned}&P_1=\left\{\{1,2,3\}\right\}\\
&P_2=\{ \{{2,3}\},\;   \{1\}\}\\
&P_3=\{\{{1,3\}},\;   \{{2\}}\}\\
&P_4=\{\{3\}  ,\;   \{1,2\}\}\\
&P_5=\{\{3\} ,\; \{2\},\;   \{1\}\}.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks! I think that I understand the problem now.

Comment: You are welcome