# Help With Proof of Theorem 1.A. in "Topics in Algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Here is a statement of the theorem. I am attempting to prove the part starting from "Conversely...".

The distinct equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on A provide us with a decomposition of A as a union of mutually disjoint subsets. Conversely, given a decomposition of A as a union of mutually disjoint, nonempty subsets, we can define an equivalence relation on A for which these subsets are the distinct equivalence classes.

I found a similar thread discussing the problem, but it did not exactly answer the question I had:
[Proof of theorem about equivalence classes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333375/proof-of-theorem-about-equivalence-classes)

So far, I have proved that the binary relation, $\sim$ defined by $x \sim y$ if and only if $x, y \in A_{\alpha}$, is an equivalence relation where $A_{\alpha}$ is an element of my paritions. Whenever I tried to prove that the set of equivalence classes are the $A_{\alpha}$'s, I got a bit stuck.

My thoughts so far are to fix an element, $i$, in my indexing set and choose an $x \in A_i$. Then $x \sim x$, so $x \in [x]$. Conversely, if $x \in [x]$, then I must prove that  $x \in A_i$. All I know so far is that $x \in A_j$ for some $j$ in my indexing set. I don't really know how to prove that $A_j = A_i$.

Comment: So did you prove the statement before "Conversely" or do you want a proof for that too?

Comment: A proof of everything before conversely was given in the book I was reading.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have a relation $\sim$ on $A = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i$, where $A_i$'s are mutually disjoint, then for set of all related pairs $\mathscr{R}$  you have $\mathscr{R} \subseteq A\times A$. This might seem to be a simple property but notice that the statement says "**we can** define an equivalence relation on A". So if we can construct one such equivalance relation, we are done. Now you have mutually disjoint, nonempty subsets of $A$ so you can construct an equivalance relation $\sim$ = $(A, \mathscr{R})$ where $$\mathscr{R} = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n (A_i \times A_i)$$ Now, let us prove that $\sim$ is an equivalance relation. Here, by definition of $A$, reflexivity holds for the relation $\sim$ because for all $x \in A$, the pair $(x,x) \in \mathscr{R}$ (this is because none of the subsets are empty and they are mutually disjoint). Symmetry also holds because if you have $x,y \in A_j$ where $A_j \subseteq A$ with $1 \le j \le n$, then for all such $x$,$y$ ,  $(x,y),(y,x) \in A_j \times A_j$. You can show that transitivity also holds with a similar argument. Again say $u,v,t \in A_k$ where $A_k \subseteq A$ with $1 \le k \le n$. Then notice that for all such $u$,$v$,$t$, $(u,v),(v,t),(u,t) \in A_k \times A_k$. Therefore $\sim$ is an equivalance relation.

Actually if you write all the elements of $A_j \times A_j$ and $A_k \times A_k$ for $A_j = \{x,y\}$ and $A_k = \{u,v,t\}$, you can see why $\sim$ = $(A, \mathscr{R})$ is an equivalance relation (For example $A_j \times A_j = \{(x,x),(x,y),(y,x),(y,y)\}$).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if fixing a set $A_i$ before defining the equivalence relation leads to success. I would suggest defining it right away for $A$ as a whole.

Let $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ be a disjoint union with $A_i \neq \emptyset$ for all $i$. Define $f: A \rightarrow \{1, \dots n\}$ with $f(a) = i \Leftrightarrow a \in A_i$*.
Now define the equivalence relation $\sim$ as:

$$
x \sim y \Leftrightarrow f(x) = f(y)
$$

This is indeed an equivalence relation which can be easily shown.

Now show that $A/\sim = \{A_1, \dots A_n\}$

- $\subseteq$: Let $B \in A/\sim$. Then $B \neq \emptyset$, therefore a $b\in B \subseteq A$ exists. Prove that $B = A_{f(b)}$.
- $\supseteq$: Show that $A_i \in A/\sim$. Because $A_i \neq \emptyset$, we have an $x\in A_i$ with $[x]_\sim \in A/\sim$. Prove that $[x]_\sim = A_i$.

*) This might look suspicious at first because it does not guarantee well-definedness of $f$, but given the disjoint union $f$ indeed maps one element from $A$ to exactly one element from $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

Actually, the theorem is stronger since it also works with an infinite number of partitions. You could think about whether or how this proof can be fixed.